# Vertex error, encoding error in azure data lake analytics while loading data. The appropriate reasons can be?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

```
USE DATABASE retail;

@log=EXTRACT id int,
item string
FROM "/Retailstock/stock.txt"
USING Extractors.Tsv();

INSERT INTO sales.stock
SELECT id, item FROM @log;
```

It is the question from Azure data lake analytics course. I need to load the table sales.stock with sales schema.
It gives vertex error and encoding error.

I can't understand the problem after head banging for 2 days. Thanks.

Comment: The error message contains a lot of information at which location the encoding error got detected. Could you share the error message information?

Comment: Hi Michael, The error occurs in the EXTRACT phase itself. In the mapping it shows 0 rows read.

Comment: If you look closely at the details of the error message, it will show you a HEX dump of the code points that caused the encoding error. That can help you figure out what encoding the data is in. Often what happens is that you have some ANSI encoding (e.g., windows-1252) with high range characters that are not supported in ASCII (7-bit) and are used as escape characters in UTF-8. If that is the case, you currently have to convert the file to UTF-8 before uploading or write your own extractor (we are working on adding support for ANSI code pages for the built-in extractors).

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to encoding mismatch. Extractors have a default encoding set to UTF8, and in case the encoding of your source file is different a runtime error will happen during extraction.

You can change the encoding by providing "encoding" parameter, e.g:

```
USING Extractors.Text(encoding : Encoding.[ASCII]);
```

See more about supported encodings here: [Extractor parameters - encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt492749.aspx#encoding)

Comment: Thanks, I will try and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case setting the encoding to ASCII in the Extractors.Text() / Extractors.Tsv() did not work. Not sure why, since the file is clearly in the ASCII encoding. I've had to manually convert the file to UTF-8.